# MongoDB update statement to remove a portion of text in a field

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongoDB collection with a field called "Url". There are many records in this collection. Inside this field, it always contains this text below:

"http://image-assets.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/"
For example "http://image-assets.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/folder1/folder2/blah.jpg"

I would like to remove the portion of "http://image-assets.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/", so the final result should look like "folder1/folder2/blah.jpg"

I would like to write a mongodb update statement, I don't know where to start. I can think of two things: (a) remove the first x number of characters, or (b) replace the text with a null. However the text includes a lot of slashes (/)

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This aggregation query with update on the result will work:

```
db.urls.aggregate( [ 
  { 
      $project: { 
          url: { 
              $split: [ 
                  "$url", 
                  "http://image-assets.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/"
              ] 
          }
      }
  } 
] ).forEach( doc => db.urls.updateOne( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { url: doc.url[1] } } )
```

With these two input documents:

```
{ url: "http://image-assets.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/folder1/folder2/blah.jpg" }
{ url: "http://image-assets.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/folder1/folder2/blah2.jpg" }
```

The updated `url` field will have values:

```
folder1/folder2/blah.jpg
folder1/folder2/blah2.jpg
```

---

[ EDIT ADD ]

Adding a check for `url` field with the URL string to be updated. Add this `$match` stage *before* the `$project` stage in the above aggregation query.

Note that in the regex search string `^` means "starts with", and the `.` (dot) is prefixed with a `\` (backslash) so that it is considered as a dot only (not as regex meta-character).

```
  { 
      $match: { 
          url: { $regex: '^http://image-assets\.s3\.us-west-2\.amazonaws\.com/' } 
      } 
  },
```

Comment: Thank you prasad_, that works.

The only thing that does not work is when it cannot find the value, and it results in a null in the resultant field.

Is there another way where we use a replace function, so that it leaves it alone if the text is not found?

Comment: You mean the filed `url` doesn't exist in some documents?

Comment: I added a check that only strings starting with "http://image-assets.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/" will be considered for the processing. If the `url` field doesn't exist _or_ if its value is `null`, then also the document will not be processed.

Comment: prasad_ you are amazingly generous with this. Thanks it works perfect.

Just another question if I simply want to replace say patter "ABC" with "XYZ", this cannot be a split. What should I use?

Comment: `db.test.updateOne( { str: "ABC" }, { $set: { str: "XYZ" } } )`; the code updates the first document that matches the criteria `str: "ABC"`. To update all documents use `updateMany`.