# MongoDB Alternatives for $set in aggregation pipeline for mongo versions older than 4.2?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have Mongo Version `4.0`, and I am trying to update inside aggregation pipeline and I found `$set` and `$unset` but they are added only in versions 4.2, that's why is there any alternatives I can use to have update in mongo versions below 4.2

Thanks

Comment: Aggregation pipeline based update (MongoDB v4.2) allows the document to be updated as a single / atomic operation (for shaping the update document and perform the update). With earlier versions, (v4.0, for example) you can still use an aggregation pipeline to shape your update document, but update it in an _additional_ operation. That is two operations to complete the task.

Comment: @prasad_ two operation? You mean update and aggregate as separate query?

Comment: _"You mean update and aggregate as separate query?"_ Yes, thats correct.

Comment: Here is an sample post with aggregate and update as two operations: [MongoDB update statement to remove a portion of text in a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60461287/mongodb-update-statement-to-remove-a-portion-of-text-in-a-field/60461623#60461623).

Comment: @prasad_ yeah but this query will be slow as It need two queries, that's why I thought of combining them as a single aggregate query.

Comment: You can upgrade your server from 4.0 to 4.2 to avail that functionality of using the aggregate with update.